# Getting/setting speaker/mic volume

Tags: android, volume

In my Android application, I would like to save the current speaker/mic volume level so that I can set it to the same level next time the application is run. I am wondering if there is any API to get/set speaker/mic volume levels.

Comment: While you are still thinking the nature of the question, another user already presented the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`AudioManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) seems to do what you need for the speaker volume. You can use the [`getStreamVolume`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getStreamVolume%28int%29) method in conjuction with one of the [`STREAM_X`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_ALARM) constants to get the volume you need and store it with [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

To set it afterwards, use the [setStreamVolume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29) method with the correct constant.

Comment: Thank you for your help. And also for understanding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for this task. Standard documentation has [lots](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) of information about it.

Comment: I think he wants to find out how to get the values and set them afterwards, not just how to store them somewhere